# IE8, iframes and unnecessary scrollbars

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8, scrollbars

For a piece of development I am doing, I need to dynamically create an Iframe with some dynamic content in it (typically an image – the image source is dynamic but the dimensions are fixed). I don’t need any scrollbars to appear on the iframe, and this is what I have done

```
<iframe id="xxxx" width="70px" height="70px" style=" scrolling: no" src="content.html">
</iframe>

//content.html
<body>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden">
        <img id="imgDiv" src="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; ">
    </div>
</body>
```

I have also tried “overflow : hidden” on the iframe but observed similar behavior.

This works all right in FF / Chrome / Safari but not in IE8!

Apparently IE reserves some space for scroll bars even after specifying that the scrollbars are not needed? An empty space is rendered on the right hand side making it look like the image is not centre aligned.. It looks really ugly in an iframe as small as the one I need here..

Is there any way around this behavior?

Comment: is there any way you can do what you need to wihtout an iframe, it seems a bit much to use one just for an image.

Comment: What I have mentioned here is a stripped down version of what I am doing - just to demonstrate the problem - and unfortunately it's an iframe that I need to use here..
But yes I managed to get this working.. It seems to be working all right, even in IE, if I add "overflow: hidden;" to the body tag of the content.html

Answer (score 5):

In the declaration of the iframe, change the style attribute **style=" scrolling: no"** for **scrolling="no"**

**Result:**
< iframe id="xxxx" width="70px" height="70px" **scrolling="no"** src="content.html" >

Answer (score 1):

To hide border use :

```
frameborder='0' scrolling='no'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a frameborder attribute you can set on iframes, give that a try

```
frameborder="0"
```